# I never get inside if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit,Mathf.Infinity, touchInputMask)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

What I want to do is when user touch a object he can move it, and specially with multitouch finger on the screen

I tried to do this ray with mouse click too, but still have the same problem

for that, I use this code on update

```
public LayerMask touchInputMask;
private static List<GameObject> touchList = new List<GameObject>();
public static Dictionary<int, objectst> touchobjects = new 
Dictionary<int, objectst>();
private GameObject[] touchesOld;
private RaycastHit hit;
public GUIText Count, IndexLift;
private Vector3 targetPos;
public struct objectst { public Vector3 screenPoint; public Vector3 offset; 
}

void Update(){

 if (nbTouches > 0)
  {
     //nbTouches = 5;
     //print(nbTouches + " touch(es) detected");
     touchesOld = new GameObject[touchList.Count];
     touchList.CopyTo(touchesOld);
     touchList.Clear();
     for (int i = 0; i < nbTouches; i++)
     {
         Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
         //print("Touch index " + touch.fingerId + " detected at 
  position " + touch.position);
         Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
         if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit,Mathf.Infinity,  
   touchInputMask))
         {
             GameObject recipient = hit.transform.gameObject;
             print("#### touch hit name object "+recipient.name);
             touchList.Add(recipient);
             //recipient.;
             if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
             {
                 print("#### tcouh begin");

                 objectst tempobj = new objectst();
                 tempobj.screenPoint = 
    Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(recipient.transform.position);
                 tempobj.offset = recipient.transform.position - 
   Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, 
  touch.position.y, tempobj.screenPoint.z));
                 touchobjects.Add(touch.fingerId, tempobj);
             }
             if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary || touch.phase 
  == TouchPhase.Moved)
             {
                 print("#### tcouh stationary or moved");
                 Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y,
                     touchobjects[touch.fingerId].screenPoint.z);
                 Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint) + touchobjects[touch.fingerId].offset;
                 print("#### objet doit être deplacer x = "+curPosition.x+"y = "+curPosition.y);
                 recipient.transform.position = curPosition;
             }
             if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
             {
                 print("#### tcouh ended");
                 Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y,
                     touchobjects[touch.fingerId].screenPoint.z);
                 Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint) - touchobjects[touch.fingerId].offset;
                 recipient.transform.position = curPosition;
             }
         }
     }
   }
 }
```

---

**EDIT**

screen shot

[image]

Comment: Do the object you are trying to touch have a colliders?

Comment: Also can you include a screenshot of your layer mask? and are you certain your objects are on that layer?

Comment: i just add a screen shot

Comment: @Eddge yes i have a rigidbody2d

the script is attached to this object i want to move, so i suppose there are in the same layer ?

Comment: Do you get inside the `for` loop? Put Debug.Log there to verify

Comment: @tamtoum1987 I was asking for a screenshot of your layer mask, what you are showing doesnt show me what is in your layer mask, also a rigidbody2d is not the same thing as a collider.  the objects you are trying to touch with your raycast need a collider.  so please post a screenshot of what is in touch input mask, and a screenshot of the inspector of an object you are trying to touch.  In order for this to work the objects you are trying to print need a collider(Not a rigidbody, as that is for physics not collisions.), and need to be on the correct layer.

Comment: Another key thing to note, your usings `physics.raycast` so your collider needs to be a 3d collider, to do a raycast against 2d collider you need to use `physics2d.raycast`

Comment: @Eddge yes it was this story of 3d that cause me problem :(

Comment: thanks for your responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing this answer based off of information I got from the comments.

In order for `Physics.Raycast` to work correctly, you first need a `Collider` on the objects you wants your `Raycast` to collide with.  If your object does not have a `Collider` then your `Raycast` will not return anything(As it didn't collide with anything).

`Collider` and `Rigidbody` are not the same thing, A `Collider` is generally used for collision detection, and is often times used by a `Rigidbody` to handle physics based collision responses.  An object with a `Rigidbody` will not collide with a `Raycast` unless that object also has a `Collider`.

`Physics` and `RigidBody` will work with only 3d Colliders. `Physics2D` and `RigidBody2D` is for dealing with 2d physics you cannot mix 2d Physics and 3d Physics components as they will not work with each other in Unity.

`LayerMask`, is a tool to determine which Collision layer you want to deal with, every object just under their name has a tag, and a layer.  This is used for determining which Collision Layer you want this object on.  If you check the physics settings you can determine which layer collide/trigger each other.

So a solution would be to add a new Layer called TouchableObject, then assign any object you want to be "Touchable" to that layer, and give it the appropriate `Collider`(2d Collider or 3d in your code you would want a 3d collider, or convert your `Physics.Raycast` call to a `Physics2D.Raycast`).  In your `Touch` script you would then make the `LayerMask` only target that layer.

Answer (score 1):

i was able to resolve the problem like this

```
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position).y), Vector2.zero, 0f);


            if (hit.rigidbody != null)
```

and of course rigidbody of hit are my object i clicked on

thanks @Eddge for your help

Comment: This is a good alternative and works on 2d plane, just change `touch.position` to `Input.mousePosition` if you want it to work for mouse click.